# Connecting to PostgreSQL database through Python code

Tags: python, postgresql, vagrant

I have a Ubuntu virtual machine using Vagrant, I set it up and run it using `vagrant up` and `vagrant ssh` and I create the database `psql -d dbname -f somesqlqueries.sql`.

Whenever I try to connect to this database through python by doing `conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=dbname")` I get this error:

> psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
>       Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
>       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Looking at solutions for this issue I changed postgresql.conf to have `listen_address = '*'` and still the same error occurs.

Also tried to turn off the firewall and run `sudo ufw allow 5432/tcp` and the error still persistent.

Comment: Are you forwarding any ports? Can you ping your vm. Also refer here https://projects.wazo.community/boards/1/topics/9211

Comment: You may need port forwarding in your vagrantfile.refer to this url https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/forwarded_ports.html

Comment: You are trying to connect via IPV6. Try, 127.0.0.1. Also when you does not specify host at psql, it connects via socket not IP, you can try `psql -h 127.0.0.1 -d dbname -f somesqlqueries.sql` to be sure PostgreSQL listens 127.0.0.1. One more thing, in case of you skip, you need to restart PostgreSQL after changing listen_address.